# FFmpeg stops encoding h265 to flv / hlc

Tags: ffmpeg

Encoding always stops at about 65 frames, the longest it goes is up to 112 frames. Then it just stops without any output. No errors, nothing. The last lines that it spits out are these:

```
 encoded 64 frames in 14.93s (4.29 fps), 869.28 kb/s, Avg QP:50.01
 [aac @ 0x55a9929450c0] Qavg: 838.802
```

Any pointers / advices would be highly appreciated as I am totally lost. The command run is as follows:

```
 ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://password:login@1.1.1.1.1:554/11 -map 0 
 -c:v libx265 -vb 300k -c:a aac -ab 38k -ar 44100 -preset veryfast -f segment 
 -segment_list /usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8 -segment_list_type hls 
 -segment_list_size 10 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 - 
 segment_wrap 30 /usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream%01d.ts
```

My camera's input is h265 video and g.726 audio. Is that the problem, perhaps? How do I change the code above to make this audio work?

The final lines of the log look like this:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://login:password@1.1.1.1:554/11':
  Metadata:
    title           : 10
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x56362603ca40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 2.9
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 8.2.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2 SSE3 Cache64
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-4 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 2 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 1 / wpp(17 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 1 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 14 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 15 / 4 / 0
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 2 / on / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-300 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=2 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip signhide tmvp fast-intra
x265 [info]: tools: strong-intra-smoothing lslices=6 deblock sao
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream0.ts' for writing
Output #0, segment, to '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream%01d.ts':
  Metadata:
    title           : 10
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 300 kb/s, 14.99 fps, 90k tbn, 14.99 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx265
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 38 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream1.ts' for writing
[rtsp @ 0x563625cecdc0] CSeq 10 expected, 7 received.bitrate=N/A dup=151 drop=0 speed=0.255x
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream2.ts' for writing
[rtsp @ 0x563625cecdc0] CSeq 11 expected, 8 received.bitrate=N/A dup=188 drop=0 speed=0.251x
[hevc @ 0x563625d0a780] Could not find ref with POC 30itrate=N/A dup=221 drop=0 speed=0.253x
[rtsp @ 0x563625cecdc0] CSeq 12 expected, 9 received.bitrate=N/A dup=264 drop=0 speed=0.244x
[hevc @ 0x563625d95900] Could not find ref with POC 35itrate=N/A dup=269 drop=0 speed=0.243x
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream3.ts' for writing
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Could not find ref with POC 0bitrate=N/A dup=370 drop=0 speed=0.248x
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream4.ts' for writing
[hevc @ 0x563625d0a780] Could not find ref with POC 29itrate=N/A dup=380 drop=0 speed=0.247x
[hevc @ 0x563625d0a780] Could not find ref with POC 20itrate=N/A dup=471 drop=0 speed=0.252x
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream5.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream6.ts' for writing
[hevc @ 0x563625d95900] Could not find ref with POC 0bitrate=N/A dup=551 drop=0 speed=0.254x
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Could not find ref with POC 22itrate=N/A dup=552 drop=0 speed=0.254x
[hevc @ 0x563625d95900] Could not find ref with POC 0bitrate=N/A dup=653 drop=0 speed=0.259x
[rtsp @ 0x563625cecdc0] CSeq 15 expected, 10 received.itrate=N/A dup=657 drop=0 speed=0.258x
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Duplicate POC in a sequence: 37.rate=N/A dup=673 drop=0 speed=0.257x
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Error parsing NAL unit #0.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing inputrop=0 speed=0.257x
[hevc @ 0x563625d95900] Could not find ref with POC 8bitrate=N/A dup=735 drop=0 speed=0.258x
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream7.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream8.ts' for writing
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Could not find ref with POC 0bitrate=N/A dup=881 drop=0 speed=0.26x
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Could not find ref with POC 33itrate=N/A dup=883 drop=0 speed=0.26x
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream9.ts' for writing
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Could not find ref with POC 0bitrate=N/A dup=932 drop=0 speed=0.26x
[rtsp @ 0x563625cecdc0] CSeq 18 expected, 11 received.itrate=N/A dup=945 drop=0 speed=0.259x
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Could not find ref with POC 2bitrate=N/A dup=952 drop=0 speed=0.259x
More than 1000 frames duplicatedN/A time=00:01:46.50 bitrate=N/A dup=958 drop=0 speed=0.259x
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream10.ts' for writing
[hevc @ 0x563625d0a780] Could not find ref with POC 0bitrate=N/A dup=1039 drop=0 speed=0.26x
[hevc @ 0x563625d0a780] Could not find ref with POC 5bitrate=N/A dup=1045 drop=0 speed=0.26x
[hevc @ 0x563625d10680] Could not find ref with POC 37itrate=N/A dup=1109 drop=0 speed=0.26x
[hevc @ 0x563625d95900] Could not find ref with POC 0bitrate=N/A dup=1110 drop=0 speed=0.26x
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream11.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writingx
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream12.ts' for writing
[segment @ 0x563625d00b80] Opening '/usr/local/nginx/html/hls/mystream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
frame= 1967 fps=3.9 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:02:11.06 bitrate=N/A dup=1206 drop=0 speed=0.261x
video:4430kB audio:368kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: unknown
x265 [info]: frame I:     16, Avg QP:25.68  kb/s: 6561.13
x265 [info]: frame P:    391, Avg QP:29.36  kb/s: 966.96
x265 [info]: frame B:   1560, Avg QP:37.01  kb/s: 38.34
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:1.5% UV:1.3%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 3.2% 0.2% 0.5% 2.2% 93.9%

encoded 1967 frames in 502.62s (3.91 fps), 275.99 kb/s, Avg QP:35.40
[aac @ 0x563625d01a40] Qavg: 129.821
```

Comment: How long does `ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://password:login@1.1.1.1.1:554/11 -map 0 -c copy -f null -` run? Share its log.

Comment: it runs for less than 1 second and the output is as follows:                     
     Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
      Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080, 29.97 
      tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
      Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
      At least one output file must be specified

Comment: My command does specify an output file. Rerun my command with `-report` added and share report.

Comment: I do not see any -report in your first command/comment. where do I put it? at the end of the entire line?

Comment: Yes at the end.

Comment: it's the same either with -report at the end or not. It says, "at least one output file must be specified".

Comment: Share the report file.

Comment: oh.. there was a typo in my try, sorry. The command is till running... it never stops. Where the report file is supposed to be located?

Comment: In the working directory. So, the input appears to be fine. Run your original command with -report added.

Comment: I checked all the directories, everything. I even searched for this file with the name given but it says no files found. It runs on a VPS with nginx.

Comment: it drops anyway either with -report added at the end or without it and I cannot find any log files for ffmpeg anywhere.

Comment: My camera's input is h265 video and g.726 audio. Is that the problem, perhaps? How do I change the code above to make this audio work?

Comment: the final lines from the log are added into my question section.